# Inconsistent wlan conection

Tags: network-manager

I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed. Everything works fine. Especially, I am happy that most of the time my computer has wlan connection 10 sec after waking up from sleep. But as I said most of the time. Does anybody have an idea why the behavior is not consistent? My wireless card is a broadcomcard

Answer (score 2):

So it's 10 seconds most of the time. How long does it take in the worse cases?

I think Ubuntu tries to establish a wireless connection every N second. Say it's every 20 seconds, then it can actually begin connecting anywhere from 0 to 20 seconds depending on when the system went to sleep and when it work up. That would be my initial guess.

Comment: It is either 10 sec or 35 sec nothing in between. If you are right where can I change the frequency of trzing to connect to a wireless. Thanks in advance.